# Are there any other ways to write these "data" sections in Assembly without the magic helpers?

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, nasm, directive

In NASM you see stuff like [this](https://50linesofco.de/post/2018-02-28-writing-an-x86-hello-world-bootloader-with-assembly):

```
msg: db "Hello world!", 0 ; we need to explicitely put the zero byte here

times 510-($-$$) db 0           ; fill the output file with zeroes until 510 bytes are full
dw 0xaa55                       ; magic number that tells the BIOS this is bootable
```

From my understanding, these are compiler-specific "helpers" (NASM being the compiler here).

It looks like the `as` compiler/program has their own helpers like `.asciz` for a similar thing:

```
msg: .asciz "Hello world!"

.fill 510-(.-init), 1, 0 # add zeroes to make it 510 bytes long
.word 0xaa55 # magic bytes that tell BIOS that this is bootable
```

Is there any "lower-level" way to write this in a compiler-agnostic way sort of thing? Somehow perhaps writing them with instructions rather than these helpers? Basically, what are these abstracting? How do I write them using lower-level abstractions?

Pretty much, I would like to write it in a more lower level way to not be bound into the specific compiler, and also know what is actually happening at a deeper level.

Same with stuff like this:

```
[bits 16]    ; use 16 bits
[org 0x7c00] ; sets the start address
```

Where do I find docs or something on how I can write this at a lower level?

Comment: From your previous questions about writing a "virtual" CPU in JS, I'd recommend against messing around with 16-bit x86 boot sectors.  Segmentation is a totally unnecessary complication.  32 or 64-bit code under Linux is nice; you can make system calls directly with `int 0x80` or `syscall` with args in registers, and you have a flat memory model.

Comment: Also, terminology: an *assembler* converts asm source into a binary object file or just a flat binary output file.  It *assembles bytes into an output file* according to each line of the source.  It's not a compiler.  **It's pretty much as low level as you get other than a hex editor, but there is no universal syntax.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you think a compiler is, but the examples you gave are of various directives (helpers, as you call them) of two different assemblers.  Assemblers are distinguished from compilers because they produce [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) from source that more or less directly represents what that machine code should be.  Compilers produce machine code from a language that doesn't try to represent the machine code that the compiler produces. Also, traditionally many compilers have worked by creating assembly code and assembling that to produce machine code, rather than by producing machine code directly.

There's no common subset of assembly language shared between all assemblers, so there's no assembler-agnostic language, lower-level or otherwise, that would let you do whatever it is you want.

However, most assembly languages can be thought of as a language that when assembled produces an output consisting of a sequence of arbitrary bytes, just specialized towards producing machine code.  This means that there is, in a way, a lowest-level almost-entirely-agnostic non-language you could use instead, and that's a binary file, which is just a sequence of arbitrary bytes. Unfortunately, there's no way you, as a human, can physically input a binary file directly into a computer without going through some other representation. The most direct but still practical way would be to use a [hex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor). A more direct, but much less practical method would be to use `cat > file.bin` on Unix or `copy con file.bin` on Windows.

Comment: No way on a *modern* computer.  Fun fact / historical note: Some ancient machines apparently had an actual array of switches on the front panel that could input binary data *directly*.  [Why did 1970s front panels prefer momentary toggle switches to push buttons?](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/12214) has pictures.

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed!  In fact, when we program our department's PDP-8/E, that's exactly how we enter the bootstrap code (i.e. the RIM loader).

Comment: @PeterCordes That's really still just a representation of the binary file you're inputting.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there are no ways to handle it in a "low-level" way, that's why we have preprocessors and macros.  Instructions like `times` provided by particular `assembler` itself and it's just helper functions, I guess not every assembler has such functions.

I used several assemblers and almost all of them have differences in providing additional features. Mostly it's ok to handle it on "high-level" because you are writing code for a particular assembler.

But if there any reasons I would like to suggest using `m4` preprocessor or any other that suits you. In this case, you could write macros for assembler in an agnostic way, but it's still extra work and most likely you don't need it.

Comment: Good call on m4, I will check that out!